# Can not save model using model.save following multi_gpu_model in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, distributed-computing, multi-gpu, keras-2

Following the upgrade to Keras 2.0.9, I have been using the `multi_gpu_model` utility but I can't save my models or best weights using

```
model.save('path')
```

The error I get is

> TypeError: can’t pickle module objects

I suspect there is some problem gaining access to the model object. Is there a work around this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras: Load checkpoint weights HDF5 generated by multiple GPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342098/keras-load-checkpoint-weights-hdf5-generated-by-multiple-gpus)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be honest, the easiest approach to this is to actually examine the multi gpu parallel model using

```
 parallel_model.summary()
```

(The parallel model is simply the model after applying the multi_gpu function). This clearly highlights the actual model (in I think the penultimate layer - I am not at my computer right now). Then you can use the name of this layer to save the model.

```
 model = parallel_model.get_layer('sequential_1)
```

Often its called sequential_1 but if you are using a published architecture, it may be 'googlenet' or 'alexnet'. You will see the name of the layer from the summary.

Then its simple to just save

```
 model.save()
```

Maxims approach works, but its overkill I think.

Rem: you will need to compile both the model, and the parallel model.

Comment: Also note that in order to get the output of intermediate layers from your model you have to unwrap the model first like GhostRider explained and then access the layers. `model.get_layer('last_dense_layer').output` e.g.

Answer (score 8):

### Workaround

Here's a patched version that doesn't fail while saving:

```py
from keras.layers import Lambda, concatenate
from keras import Model
import tensorflow as tf

def multi_gpu_model(model, gpus):
  if isinstance(gpus, (list, tuple)):
    num_gpus = len(gpus)
    target_gpu_ids = gpus
  else:
    num_gpus = gpus
    target_gpu_ids = range(num_gpus)

  def get_slice(data, i, parts):
    shape = tf.shape(data)
    batch_size = shape[:1]
    input_shape = shape[1:]
    step = batch_size // parts
    if i == num_gpus - 1:
      size = batch_size - step * i
    else:
      size = step
    size = tf.concat([size, input_shape], axis=0)
    stride = tf.concat([step, input_shape * 0], axis=0)
    start = stride * i
    return tf.slice(data, start, size)

  all_outputs = []
  for i in range(len(model.outputs)):
    all_outputs.append([])

  # Place a copy of the model on each GPU,
  # each getting a slice of the inputs.
  for i, gpu_id in enumerate(target_gpu_ids):
    with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % gpu_id):
      with tf.name_scope('replica_%d' % gpu_id):
        inputs = []
        # Retrieve a slice of the input.
        for x in model.inputs:
          input_shape = tuple(x.get_shape().as_list())[1:]
          slice_i = Lambda(get_slice,
                           output_shape=input_shape,
                           arguments={'i': i,
                                      'parts': num_gpus})(x)
          inputs.append(slice_i)

        # Apply model on slice
        # (creating a model replica on the target device).
        outputs = model(inputs)
        if not isinstance(outputs, list):
          outputs = [outputs]

        # Save the outputs for merging back together later.
        for o in range(len(outputs)):
          all_outputs[o].append(outputs[o])

  # Merge outputs on CPU.
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    merged = []
    for name, outputs in zip(model.output_names, all_outputs):
      merged.append(concatenate(outputs,
                                axis=0, name=name))
    return Model(model.inputs, merged)
```

You can use this `multi_gpu_model` function, until the bug is fixed in keras. Also, when loading the model, it's important to provide the tensorflow module object:

```py
model = load_model('multi_gpu_model.h5', {'tf': tf})
```

### How it works

The problem is with `import tensorflow` line in the middle of `multi_gpu_model`:

```py
def multi_gpu_model(model, gpus):
  ...
  import tensorflow as tf
  ...
```

This creates a closure for the `get_slice` lambda function, which includes the number of gpus (that's ok) and tensorflow module (not ok). Model save tries to serialize all layers, including the ones that call `get_slice` and fails exactly because `tf` is in the closure.

The solution is to move import out of `multi_gpu_model`, so that `tf` becomes a global object, though still needed for `get_slice` to work. This fixes the problem of saving, but in loading one has to provide `tf` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim for the patch. I want to know whether this will work if i give multi_gpu_model(model, 1).

Answer (score 0):

It's something that need a little work around by loading the multi_gpu_model weight to the regular model weight.
e.g.

```
#1, instantiate your base model on a cpu
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model = create_model()

#2, put your model to multiple gpus, say 2
multi_model = multi_gpu_model(model, 2)

#3, compile both models
model.compile(loss=your_loss, optimizer=your_optimizer(lr))
multi_model.compile(loss=your_loss, optimizer=your_optimizer(lr))

#4, train the multi gpu model
# multi_model.fit() or multi_model.fit_generator()

#5, save weights
model.set_weights(multi_model.get_weights())
model.save(filepath=filepath)
```

`

refrence: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/8123

Comment: Sorry to hear that.. can you share the new errors you got or the code you are using?